# Shall I use 'thus' or 'thusly'?

Tags: word-choice, adverbs, archaicisms, intensifying-adverbs

Which is correct?

> ...others are compensated thus.
>
> ...others are compensated thusly.

This page says 'thusly' is incorrect: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/thusly
However without the 'ly' is sounds wrong.

This page on adverbs didn't mention adverbs at the end of a sentence as being wrong. http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/adverbs.htm

It provides some examples:

> A viewpoint adverb generally comes after a noun and is related to an adjective that precedes that noun:
>
> A successful athletic team is often a good team *scholastically*.

I just think '...a good team scholastical' would be wrong. Why is 'thus' different?

This related question also says 'thus' over 'thusly', but the word was not at the end of a sentence. ["Thus" vs. "Thusly"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91269/thus-vs-thusly)

Comment: (BTW -- My crystal ball tells me that you perhaps really meant "should", not "shall" in your question.)

Comment: The word "thusly" is in the dictionaries I quickly consulted, e.g. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thusly -- Even the online dictionary you've linked to seems to think it is a word, though one that many might not accept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The suffix -ly is used to form adverbs out of words that aren't already adverbs. "Thus" is already an adverb. There is no word "thusly." "Thusly" is sometimes used as a joke to indicate that the speaker is pretending to adopt a fancy style of speech and using a word that doesn't exist. A similar joke-word is "bestest;" "best" is already the superlative, so it doesn't need another "-est."

The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language says:

> *Thusly* is occasionally employed humorously, for mock-stylish effects. Otherwise, as a variant of *thus* (itself an adverb), *thusly* is termed unacceptable by 97 per cent of the Usage Panel.

Comment: So just one of the exceptions in English?

Comment: @Chloe: It's not an exception because there is no rule that adverbs end in -ly. For example, "together" is an adverb.

Comment: Another example would be _well_, which is also an adverb. You wouldn't say, “He speaks Spanish welly”, either.

Comment: Or even wellly. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Thusly has a reputation for not being a 'real world' but it is certainly used like one frequently. It has been in the OED since the first edition in 1912 (although it's designated as a colloquialism) and it has been in published writing for well over a century. While the one of the first published appearances of the word referenced in the OED was used ironically in the December edition of Harper's in 1862  (*"It happened, as J. Billings would say, ‘thusly’"*) it has also been used with some seriousness such as in The Life of Captain Sir Richard F. Burton in 1898 (*"Stories never lose anything in the recital, and consequently this one grew thusly."*) Interestingly use of the word is showing a marked decline relative to the early 1980s:

[image: Thusly ngrams]

In most of these contexts, "Thusly" is used to mean "in a manner corresponding to that which indicated previously." So the phrase "we shall act thusly" would be correct when "we shall act thus" will not be although "we shall thus act" might be the most correct.

Comment: There is no such thing as a thus manner. Thus is not an adjective. “We shall act thus” is perfectly correct. “We shall thus act” is not incorrect, but it is awkward and means something else: “We shall therefore act”.

Comment: The fact that occurs doesn't mean it's a word. Did you know that I uptygupqqqfize every morning before I brush my teeth? Now "uptygupqqqfize" has occurred on the web.

Comment: FWIW, I think the more usual spelling is **uptigoupqqqfise**, at least in AE.

Comment: Some people spell it thusly, but I think uptygupqqqfize is betterer.

Comment: I don't think it's productive to get into debates about who gets to be the word police or what is or is not a word. It's absurd to  posit that "uptygupqqqfize" has as much meaning as the combination of letters in "thusly." OP was asking about when the two terms are used in English and it if would be appropriate to end a sentence with a constructed adverb. S/he was not asking if the word itself exists. Also, perhaps more importantly, the word "Thusly" has been in the OED since its first edition in 1912 and at the end of sentences in published writing since it first appeared in 1865.

Comment: +1 -- in the understanding that you'll provide a few excerpts and maybe links to decent dictionaries which treat "thusly" as a real word. :)

Comment: Note that the graphs that Google present on their search of words show the use of words in books, not the Internet. The graph shown here looks very much like the one Google shows. And the answer mentions examples from books, again, not the Internet.