# Thus vs thusly for mathematicians

Tags: vocabulary

My expertise is in math & science, not grammar.  For mathematicians, 'thus' is generally seen as a synonym for 'therefore'.  If I were to write, "The equation should be written thus:", most would tend to interpret this as "The equation should be written **therefore**:". On the other hand, if I were to write, "The equation should be written thusly:", this would be interpreted as "The equation should be written **as follows**:".  In this case, is 'thus' still considered preferable to 'thusly'?  This is now just a matter of curiosity since I think I've already decided to replace 'thusly' with 'as follows'.

Comment: Use of *thusly* is a blasphemy against the Holy Spirit which will earn the sinner an eternity proofreading MBA theses.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Thus" vs. "Thusly"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91269/thus-vs-thusly) Also [Shall I use 'thus' or 'thusly'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152342/)

Comment: Actually, both terms are a bit archaic, but *thusly* more than *thus*.

Answer (score 3):

> [**thus**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/thus)
>   adverb  *literary or formal*
>
> 1. As a result or consequence of this; therefore:
>      *'Burke knocked out Byrne, **thus** becoming champion'*
>      Synonyms: **consequently**, as a consequence, in consequence, thereby, so, that being so, therefore, ergo, accordingly, hence, as a result, for that reason, ipso facto, because of that, on that account
> 2. In the manner now being indicated or exemplified; in this way:
>      *'she phoned Susan, and while she was **thus** engaged, Charles summoned the doctor'*
>      Synonyms: **like that**, in that way, so, like so
> 3. [as submodifier] To this point; so:
>      *'the website has been cracked three times **thus** far'*
>      Synonyms: **so far**, until now, up until now, up to now, up to this point, hitherto
>
> [**thusly**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/thusly)
>   adverb  *informal*
>
> - Another term for thus (sense 2).
>     *'the review was conducted thusly'*

The definitions quoted above indicate that:

- *thusly* is a synoym of only one meaning/usage of the word *thus*, namely the meaning "In the manner now being indicated or exemplified; in this way" (sense 2).  This would seem to equate to your desired meaning of "as follows".
- *thusly* is **not** a synoym of *thus* when used to mean "therefore" (sense 1).

So, yes, you could use *thusly* to mean "as follows", but — as you suggest — in your particular situation, it is probably better to use an alternative expression.

Personally, I would say that *thusly* is obscure and rarely used (at least in British English) these days.

Answer (score 1):

*"thus"* has various meanings, *one* of which is synonymous with "therefore", and another meaning "like this" or "in this way".

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/thus

> 1. In this manner: Lay the pieces out thus. See Usage Note at thusly.
> 2. To a stated degree or extent; so.
> 3. Therefore; consequently: *Thus it was necessary for me to resign*.
> 4. For example: *Few of the nation's largest cities are state capitals; thus neither New York nor Chicago is the seat of its state's government*.

"The equation should be written thus" is an example of the "in this way" meaning, not "therefore", and we can see this in your example sentence, which is plainly wrong:  we would not write *"The equation should be written therefore:"*

*thusly* is a colloquial usage of "thus" without any additional meaning, and should be avoided unless you deliberately want it to look like it was written hundreds of years ago.

EDIT:  with reference to your last point, about using "as follows" instead of "thus":  Personally I think that "as follows" is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the Oxford English Dictionary entries for "[thus](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/201582)" and "[thusly](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/201585)"—which are behind a paywall, as is the entire online OED—I can tell you the following. The first documented usage of "thusly" occurs in 1865 in the New York-based *Harper's Magazine*. "Thusly", like "thus", is an adverb, and a synonym for one of the older documented usages of "thus", "In this way, like this," **but not** for "In accordance with this; accordingly, and so; consequently; therefore."

So, while you're correct in saying that "thusly" isn't synonymous with "therefore," "thus" already can mean "In the following manner; as follows; in these words." Moreover, since "thusly" was first constructed by adding the adverbial "-ly" suffix to "thus," this, I want to speculate, probably happened as a form of hypercorrection, as a way of making the adverb "thus" appear even more like an adverb. So stay away from "thusly," not because it's too florid or non-standard, but because compared to "thus" it's grammatically redundant.

Comment: The other answers here indicate that *thus* and *thusly* do **not** "both mean the same thing" in all cases; although they do have the meaning 
"as follows" or "in this way" in common.

Comment: Thanks, it seems you're right. I've rewritten my entire answer to make that clear.