# Is the use of the word "thus" still common practice?

Tags: meaning, british-english

I have quite some reservations regarding the use of the word "thus". Often I see people using it as as substitute for "consequently".

I have always taken the word to mean "in this way". E.g I perform the calculation thus.

Is the word still in common usage, whenever I see it I can't help but feel the author is being pretentious - or in some cases flat out using it incorrectly.

If anyone has some insight on this let me know - especially if I am wrong!

Comment: It is still in use in BrE. Never use a long word when a short one will do.

Comment: [macmillandictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/thus) gives the two definitions as **1:** ***as a result of** [the fact that you have just mentioned]* and **2:** ***in the way** [that has been mentioned, or **by the method** [that has been mentioned]* (dictionaries usually define the the most common usage first).

Comment: @Mick a good point well made!

Comment: @Mick: Okay, it's a bit facetious, but I have no problem with using the longer form [***thusly***](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91269/thus-vs-thusly) sometimes - always and only with the ***in that manner*** sense.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm inclined to agree with you! For some reason *thusly* feels more acceptable - I have no idea why, it just does. I feel like thus belong sin the same category of redundant old English. But as you said in your comment it seems perfectly valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still use *thus* and am under the impression that it is still widely used in today's day and age.

You are correct about its definition and usage, but it also has a second definition and usage.

> Thus
>
> 1. As a result or consequence of this; therefore. *Syn: therefore, consequently*
> 2. In the manner now being indicated or exemplified; in this way. *Syn: like that, in that way*

The Ngram also shows us that *thus* is still widely used:

[image: Ngram]

***Thus***, we can conclude that *thus* is still an acceptable, correct, and widely used word.

Comment: I just checked the OED and it agrees with what you just said. I don't like the use of this as a replacement for consequently, but it appears to be valid!